# Gran problema de eficiencia. Tips para optimizar hash table en C?

Tags: c

Buenas, estoy implementando el algoritmo de Greedy para colorear grafos. Los grafos pueden tener hasta `1 000 000` de vértices. Todos los enteros son `uint_32`, y para guardarlos utilizo una hash table que utiliza arrays dinámicos para solucionar las colisiones (y no listas enlazadas porque lei que de esta forma se optimiza).

En teoría debería correr el algoritmo en minutos, pero solo cargar el grafo me demora una hora.. ¿Alguna recomendación? En el código uso `calloc` en lugar de `malloc` por que leí que para hash tables se recomienda.

¿Vos me recomendas usar `malloc`? O puede que el algoritmo sea muy ineficiente por que mi sistema operativo es lento (Tengo ubuntu 32 bits con 1 Gb de RAM) .

Aca muestro el codigo de las estructuras y como se las crea.

```
struct _tabla_type {
     uint32_t tamanho;
     elemento_t *tabla; //array dinamico de elemenot_t
};

//inicializar (n = numero de vertices)
tabla_type nuevatabla(uint32_t n) {
    assert(n > 0);
    size_t h = sizeStructelem(); // el tamaño de la structura correspondiente (esta en otro .c por lo que no la puedo acceder directamente)
    tabla_type table = NULL;
    table = calloc(1, sizeof( struct _tabla_type)) ;
    table->tamanho = n;
    table->tabla = calloc(n,  sizeof(h));
    for (uint32_t i = 0 ; i < table->tamanho; i++)
    {
     table->tabla[i] = NULL;
    }

    return table;
}

// Cada indice de la tabla anterior tiene un elemento de la sig
// estructura, que es un array de dinamicos de vertices que colisionaron
//por la funcion hash
struct _elemento_t{
    VerticeSt *array_vertex;
    uint32_t used;
    uint32_t size;
};

// agregar elemento 
elemento_t newElement(uint32_t vertice, uint32_t vecino, elemento_t b) {
    VerticeSt Vertice = NuevoVertice(vertice,vecino);
    if (b == NULL){
        b = calloc(1, sizeof(struct _elemento_t));
        b->array_vertex = calloc(1, sizeof(struct _VerticeSt));
        b->array_vertex[0] = Vertice;
        b->used = 1;
        b->size = 1;
    }
    else{
        if (b->used == b->size) {
            b->size *= 2;
            b->array_vertex = (VerticeSt *)realloc(b->array_vertex, b->size * sizeof(struct _VerticeSt));
      }
      b->array_vertex[b->used++] = Vertice;
  }
 return b;
}


// en los correspondientes .h esta typedef struct _tabla_type *tabla_type

// y typedef struct _elemnto_t *elemento_t
```

Comment: Sin mostrar algun codigo, muy dificil que se te pueda ayudar

Comment: coincido con Gerardo, además me surge una pregunta, lo has probado en otra plataforma? pero si aquí dependes bastante de la memoria.

Comment: si mal, ahí subí el código. No lo probé en otra plataforma, me voy a fijar gracias

Answer (score 1):

Creo que el problema lo tienes en que haces millones de peticiones de memoria dinámica.(parece que mínimo 2 millones)

Tienes una estructura dinámica con elementos muy pequeños pero extremadamente numerosos.

Dependiendo del hardware que tarde una hora me parece hasta poco tiempo.

La solución es reducir las peticiones de memoria dinámica, no te puedo ser más concreto por que me faltaria el código de la implementación pero yo optaria por no hacer peticiones de memoria de cada uno de los vértices.  O bien usar memoria estática  o bien buscar otra solución, pero eso está machacado tu rendimiento.

Aparte de eso, si realmente quieres velocidad, tendrías que revisarte el uso de [ensamblador SSE](http://lordpakus.blogspot.com.es/2011/08/curso-de-programacion-capitulo-7.html) . Es la manera de obtener máxima velocidad y creo que para tu caso te podría ir bien.

El único problema es que has de plantearte las estructuras de memoria para que puedan aprovechar al máximo la velocidad pero eso ya será otra pregunta :D

Answer (score 1):

Matemáticamente, un grafo y una relación binaria es lo mismo (isomorfismo).

Una relación binaria se puede "representar" con `NxN` booleanos.

Si el número de booleanos a `true` (se puede decir que el número de enlaces del grafo) es pequeño en comparación al numero `NxN`, una de las posibles estructuras de datos para representarlo es una "Sparse Matrix de booleanos".

Si los nodos no son nodos de números ordenados de (0 o 1) a N, sino Strings o cualquier número, se necesita un tabla hash que a cada String le asocie un índice para la Sparse Matrix.

Un ejemplito de Sparse Matrix: 
https://github.com/uestla/Sparse-Matrix